# aws lambda access to container running on ec2 in vpc and aws services in the same time

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-vpc

I have lambda that is deployed in VPC in public subnet. It needs a docker container access on EC2 instance. All good and it has it via inbound rule that allows traffic on the container port.
But the same lambda is trying to make a call to bedrock service which timeouts. When I remove VPC configuration the bedrock request is working fine. I created outbound rule to lambda security group that allows access to any domain over internet but this doesn't change much
I was hinted that I need a NAT gateway for my lambda. But my VPC has 6 subnets and I have to create 6 NATs which consumes a lot of resources.
I also tried to open the container port for internet access and it worked but this is too risky for me unless I can limit the IPs to a specific range where my lambda resides. I found the IP ranges list maintained by Amazon, but then I realized that this list is subject to change over time so I can not rely entirely on it.
I can not come with better idea how to restrict access on public IP only for calls coming from my lambda

Any suggestions what would be my best setup will be very welcomed.

I think that the obvious solution is to disband lambda function and move its code in another docker container in the same VPC but I want to do that when there is no other solution because this will invoke an additional work, not only in coding, but scaling and etc. after that.

Answer (score 1):

Please see [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77351234/how-to-start-ecs-fargate-task-using-aws-lambda-dotnet-timeout-problem/77352062#77352062) regarding your options for allowing your Lambda function to access resources (like Bedrock) which are outside your VPC. Note that Amazon Bedrock supports [VPC Endpoints](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/privatelink/aws-services-privatelink-support.html), so that is probably the way to go.

---

> I was hinted that I need a NAT gateway for my lambda. But my VPC has 6 subnets and I have to create 6 NATs

That's not how NAT Gateways work at all. You don't create one per subnet.

You would only place NAT Gateway(s) in your public subnets (subnets with Internet Gateways) and then configure the route tables in your private subnets (subnets without an Internet Gateway) to route traffic to the NAT Gateway(s). You could have a single NAT Gateway in your VPC, in one of your public subnets, and configure all your private subnet route tables to route to that one NAT Gateway.

You would only need a minimum of 1 NAT Gateway per VPC, and if you were concerned with failover/disaster-recovery then you would create at most 1 NAT Gateway per availability zone.

Comment: Ah, this makes sense. Anyway I decided to split logic in two lambda functions. One will be deployed in VPC and work with resources in this VPC. The other one will make calls to aws services (bedrock in my example)